# In Vue, how do I use require() to reference multiple images in srcset

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a template that looks like this

```
<template>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 700px)" :srcset="require(`@/assets/img/${image}.webp`)" type="image/webp" />
    <source
      media="(min-width: 100px)"
      :srcset="`@/assets/img/${image}_small.webp 1x, @/assets/img/${image}.webp` 2x"
      type="image/webp"
    />
    <source media="(min-width: 700px)" :srcset="`@/assets/img/${image}.jpg`" />
    <img
      id="mainImg"
      :src="require(`@/assets/img/${image}.jpg`)"
      :srcset="`@/assets/img/${image}_small.jpg 1x, @/assets/img/${image}.jpg 2x`"
      :alt="altText"
    />
  </picture>
</template>
```

When there is only one image in srcset I can simply do

```
:srcset="require(`@/assets/img/${image}.webp`)"
```

But when there is more than one image I can't do something like this

```
:srcset="require(`@/assets/img/${image}_small.webp 1x, @/assets/img/${image}.webp 2x`)"
```

How can I use require in a srcset tag that has 1x and 2x version?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img :srcset="require(`@/assets/img/${image}_small.webp`) + ' 1x, '
            + require(`@/assets/img/${image}.webp`) + ' 2x'">
```

should work.

`require()` simply replaces your project relative paths (which are strings) with paths to the minified resources bundled by webpack (which are also strings). But if you want `require()` to match the assets, you have to pass them one by one, and do the concatenation required by `srcset` yourself, using `require()`'s resulting paths.
If you give `require()` a big string containing multiple concatenated paths, it won't magically detect and replace each.